# Find probaility of failure using logistic regression in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get some insights from a dataset using Logistic Regression. The starting dataframe has the information of if something was removed unscheduled (1 = Yes and 0 = No) and some data which was provided with this removal.
This looks like this:

[image: Snippet of dataset]

This data is then 'dummyfied' using `pandas.get_dummies`, where the result is as expected. 
Then I normalized the found coefficients (using **coef_**) to scale everything the same. I put this in a dataframe with the column 'Parameter' (which is the column name of the dummy dataframe) and the column 'Value' (which is the value obtained using the coefficients).

Now I will get the following result.

[image: Result]

Now this result shows that the On-wing Time is the biggest contributor in the unscheduled removal.

Now the question: how can I predict what the chance is that there will be an unscheduled removal for this reason (this column)? So, what is the chance that I will get another unscheduled removal which is caused by the On-wing Time?

Note that these parameters can change since this data is fake data and data may be added later on. So when the biggest contributor changes, the prediction should also focus on the new biggest contributor.

I hope you understand the question.

**EDIT**

The complete code and dataset (fake one) can be found here: 1drv.ms/u/s!AjkQWQ6EO_fMiSEfu3vYgSTBR0PZ

Ganesh

Comment: A snippet of dataset won’t help us. Please paste your sample data.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show our efforts.

Comment: Of course. Please find the complete code + dataset in OneDrive using this link: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjkQWQ6EO_fMiSEfu3vYgSTBR0PZ

Comment: Logistic Regression has predict_proba() if you're interested in "what is the chance...". 2. scaling coef_ sounds odd but maybe it's a normal thing. Most things I've seen are people scaling the input data before-hand. 3. Why are you most interested in what the biggest contributor is? What do you plan to do with that info? 4. There's ClassifierChain for [chained classification tasks](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.ClassifierChain.html)

Comment: Hi Jared, 2. Scaling the input data before-hand is a good idea, but how can I do this looking at my code? 3. I'm a graduate student who is doing a research to see to what extend data mining can help to focus the analysis more. One of the things to do this is to look for the biggest contributor in a dataset, so that the analysis can focus itself to that contributor. It is just to see if this is possible and (more important) how this is possible. Did I do something wrong here?